# Real Life Situation: How many days a student will be scheduled to be in the classroom if every seat is filled and seats are distributed equitably

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to figure out a relative easy Math problem, but I'm think somewhere I did a mistake.

It is a real life situation regarding pandemic situation.

In a school classroom there are totally $20$ empty seats and totally $26$ students.
For how many times a student has to be in the classroom in a month (assuming $20$ school days in a month)

---

Later Edit:

having $26$ students and only $20$ empty seats, it is needed to find how many days a student will be scheduled to be in the classroom if every seat is filled and seats are distributed equitably

The case when a student is in a sick leave is not relevant.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're asking how many times does a student need to be in the classroom in a month for what to happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @900edges having $26$ students and only $20$ empty seats, it is needed to find out how often a single student has to be in the classroom in a month ($20$ working days) - it is mandatory all the seats to be occupied every day. 

The case when a student is in a sick leave is not relevant.

Comment: It sounds like you want to find how many days a student will be scheduled to be in the classroom if every seat is filled and seats are distributed equitably.  Saying how often a student has to be in the classroom is not clear.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes, indeed. Thank you! with your permission i will edit my questions with your words. thank you!

Comment: I think the question is "if every student is seated in the classroom for the same amount of time, how much time would that be?" due to the phrase "the seats are distributed equitably"

Comment: @BGandul what work have you done so far? what's your thought process

Comment: Hint: $~(20 \times 20) \div 26 = 15,~$ with a remainder of $~10.~$  So, if every student attends exactly $~15~$ classes, how many empty seats would you still have to fill, each month?

Comment: @user2661923 Could you please elaborate your response into the answer section? thanks

Comment: @user2661923 i see, but not having math background (being a history teacher) it's not so easy for me to follow you. thanks

Comment: Based on your last comment, I am going to answer your posted question.

Comment: Each day, you give 20 candies to children ; at the end of the month, you have given 20x20=400 candies. If you share equitably those 400 candies to 26 children, each child has received 400/26=15 or 16 candies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the OP (i.e. original poster) left an explanatory comment that he is a history teacher, with (presumably) no math training, I don't feel that it is reasonable to ask him to *show work*, in how to handle this **real life situation**.

$(20 \times 20) \div 26 = 15,~$ with a remainder of $~10.~$

This implies that if each of the $~26~$ students attend exactly $~15~$ classes each, there will be exactly $~10~$ empty seats, throughout the month.

So, if you arbitrarily select $~10~$ of the $~26~$ students, and have those students each attend one extra class, that will precisely fill the seats.

So, you have that

- $~(26-10) = 16 \times 15 = 240.$ 
  This refers to $~16~$ students attending $~15~$ classes each.
- $~10 \times 16 = 160.$ 
  This refers to $~10~$ students attending $~16~$ classes each.

This way, you end up using $~240 + 160 = 400 = (20 \times 20)~$ seats, during the month.